# How do I center content in a div using CSS?

Tags: css

How do I center content in a div both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: thomas see this also http://www.vdotmedia.com/demo/css-vertically-center.html

Comment: He is asking, "How do i center the contents of a div, vertically and horizontally."

Comment: For horizontal align perhaps this helps: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: As far as I have looked there is no way to horizontally center a content within div. Tables are the only option here.

Comment: There are only two hard problems in programming: Cache invalidation and centering things in css.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update 2020:

There are several options available*:

> *Disclaimer: This list may not be complete.

**Using Flexbox**
Nowadays, we can use flexbox. It is quite a handy alternative to the css-transform option. I would use this solution almost always. If it is just one element maybe not, but for example if I had to support an array of data e.g. rows and columns and I want them to be relatively centered in the very middle.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border: 1px dotted #333;
}

.item {
  /* default => flex: 0 1 auto */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px dotted #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item">I am centered in the middle.</div>
  <div class="item">I am centered in the middle, too.</div>
</div>
```

---

**Using CSS 2D-Transform**
This is still a good option, was also the accepted solution back in 2015.
It is very slim and simple to apply and does not mess with the layouting of other elements.

```css
.boxes {
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.h-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.v-center span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box h-center">horizontally centered lorem ipsun dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="box v-center"><span>vertically centered lorem ipsun dolor sit amet lorem ipsun dolor sit amet</span></div>
  <div class="box h-center v-center"><span>horizontally and vertically centered lorem ipsun dolor sit amet</span></div>
</div>
```

> Note: This does also work with `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements.

---

**Using Grid**
This might just be an overkill, but it depends on your DOM. If you want to use grid anyway, then why not. It is very powerful alternative and you are really maximum flexible with the design.

> Note: To align the items vertically we use flexbox in combination with
> grid. But we could also use `display: grid` on the items.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border: 1px dotted #333;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dotted #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item-large {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item item-large">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

---

### Further reading:

[CSS article about grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid)
[CSS article about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
[CSS article about centering without flexbox or grid](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements)

Answer (score 21):

To align horizontally it's pretty straight forward:

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
body  {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.bodyclass #container { 
    width: ???px; /*SET your width here*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
} 
</style>
<body class="bodyclass ">
<div id="container">type your content here</div>
</body>
```

and for vertical align, it's a bit tricky: 
here's the [source](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
  <style>
    .greenBorder {border: 1px solid green;} /* just borders to see it */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="greenBorder" style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
        any text<br>
        any height<br>
        any content, for example generated from DB<br>
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want content in the div should be center horizontally and vertically. not center div in the page.

Answer (score 0):

with all the adjusting css.
if possible, wrap it with a table
with height and width as 100% and
td set it to vertical align to middle, text-align to center

Answer (score 0):

By using transform: works like a charm!

```
<div class="parent">
    <span>center content using transform</span>
    </div>

    //CSS
    .parent {
        position: relative;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    .parent span {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```