# I cannot figure out how to center my div content

Tags: css

Using my code posted below.

I want to center the div and the text inside to the center of the webpage. My end result is still showing div and content on the top left.

I have tried setting margins to 0 auto.

```css
a {
    float: left;
    width: 8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0094ff;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    margin-left:0 auto;
    margin-right:0 auto;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #00ff90;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}


 div {
    
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

 #horizontal-list ul {
     list-style:none;
     width:10%;
     padding-right:20px;
}

 #horizontal-list ul li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

Html below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Sitestyles.css">
    <title>blahblah</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu-outer">
        <div class="table">
            <ul id="horizontal-list">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [center content in div with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374650/center-content-in-div-with-css)

Comment: where is html code?, your code didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a width to the `div` you want to center. Otherwise the `margin:auto;` will not know how to calculate the margins.

Here is an example of how to do this - [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqbjzuxn/1/)

And here is the code that makes this possible:

```
.table{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%
}
```

Here is also a definitive guide to [centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

If you had something else in mind, comment below. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I seem to get confused and think that setting width for div would change the elements width.