# Content positioned in Y and X middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't want my content positioned in middle along the X axis, I want the content in the middle of the Y axis to.

In my CSS I've used the following to prevent the page becoming any bigger

```
html { overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden }
```

and below is what I want to achieve. Just as an example, imagine a box in the middle. I believe this can be done with JavaScript, I'm just not sure how.

[image: Example Image]

So the image above shows the box in the middle on both X and Y axis. Please don't post how to position it in the middle along X Axis like this website as that's not what I would like.

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [center content in div with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374650/center-content-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your div or box's CSS properties to..

```
div {
  /* These first 3 can change */
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* The important stuff below */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

}
```

See it in action in the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function to dynamically center along either axes relative to the parent element.  Set the parent container's overflow property to hidden and set the child element's marginTop value to the value of:  center(child width, parent width)

```
center= function(Win,Wout){
  return (Wout-Win)/2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript as Nick said, but is CSS also an option? If you want to vertically center a child element with CSS, you can do so as shown in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bjf10vyj/
The parent position must be relative, and then the child

```
position: absolute;    
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```