# How to center buttons inline on a webpage

Tags: css

I'm wondering how on earth I can have three buttons on the same line that are then centered on the line, with ample space between the buttons. I've tried inline-flex, I've tried inline-block, all sorts of stuff and I just can't seem to figure it out.

```css
.buttoncontainer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    flex-grow: 2;
}

.inlinebutton {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:200px;
    width: 350px;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url('./profile.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    padding: auto;
    border: 50px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here's the code I'm working with. I was trying to wrap 3 buttons in the .buttoncontainer div and change each of the individual inline buttons to have different code, but I'm wondering if there's a different way to go about it.

### I essentially want:

### |    _____   _____    _____    |
|   |    |  |    |   |    |    |
|   |foo |  |bar |   |foo2|    |
|   ------  ------   ------    |
|                              |

But I have:

---

### |        __________ _____      |
|       |    ||    ||    |     |
|       |foo ||bar ||foo2|     |
|       ------------------     |
|                              |

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/710Pu.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToYrZ.png)

(Also sorry if there's something up with the formatting, this is my very first question and I'm not quite sure how to use this site yet)

Comment: [**ADD** THE HTML in your snippet !](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: have a look at `display: flex`, `justify-content: center`, `align-items:center`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I center content in a div using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374650/how-do-i-center-content-in-a-div-using-css)

Comment: You were nearly there with the display: inline-flex. Had you used display: flex you'd have probably nailed it. I've put an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simplest to use display:flex.  You can justify the contents to the center and then use the gap property to put plenty of space between the buttons. If you just want the buttons spaced evenly then use justify-content:space-evenly and don't use gap. See the example below

```css
.flex1 {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  gap:1rem;
}

.flex2 {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex1'>
  <div>
    <button>Button1</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Button1</button>
  </div>
   <div>
    <button>Button1</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br><!-- Just a bit of space between the two divs-->
<div class='flex2'>
  <div>
    <button>Button4</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Button5</button>
  </div>
   <div>
    <button>Button6</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's a great resource that explains it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you so much! After I tried out this code I was able to work with the margins and padding to get it to work perfectly!!

Comment: That's great to hear! :-)

Comment: If you could hit the up arrow above the number. I need some good reputation

Comment: Unfortunately I tried but it says I need reputation myself before it'll let me... but believe me I tried!!