# Have grid row vertically aligned in relation to itself

Tags: css

I have a simple grid:

[image]

I'm trying to get all the items vertically aligned within the limit they have, but item Two to on the same vertical line of Three

```css
h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">One</div>
  <div class="box2">Two</div>
  <div class="box3">Three</div>
  <div class="box4">Four</div>
  <div class="box5">Five</div>
</div>
```

If I change the `.wrapper div` to:

```
.wrapper div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```css
.wrapper div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-self: center;
}

h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">One</div>
  <div class="box2">Two</div>
  <div class="box3">Three</div>
  <div class="box4">Four</div>
  <div class="box5">Five</div>
</div>
```

I'll get that alignment, but item Two will be vertically centered within its container, not at the same line of item Three:

[image]

Is it possible to have item Two and Three at the vertical center of item Three with CSS grid?

Something like:

[image]

The idea is that item Two doesn't go between Three and Five, but at the exact vertical line of item Three

Comment: it would be much helpful if you could add expected output image :)

Comment: You're right adding now

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: Is this just a simple example or is it what you need? ie does item 5 always have the same height as item 3 and item 2 have twice that height? And can you add to the HTML or is that not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like the following for the grid-layout:

```css
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  /* changed to 4 from 5 */
}


/* assumed from output img */

.box5 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">One</div>
  <div class="box2">Two</div>
  <div class="box3">Three</div>
  <div class="box4">Four</div>
  <div class="box5">Five</div>
</div>
```

For the alignment of the items inside the boxes you could use e.g. `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;`. There are other options if you don't like the flex option you can also do it with `display: block` i.e. with absolute positioning and transform - but I'd not recommend it.

I have written a longer answer a few years ago but it still holds true:
[How do I center content in a div using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374650/how-do-i-center-content-in-a-div-using-css/28507787#28507787)

Comment: Yes almost, but how would you vertically align all the items inside their boxes?

Comment: @sir-haver,  ``display: flex; align-items: center;``.

Comment: @sir-haver You have multiple options. There is css-transform that you could use or display flex or display grid (sub-grid). I've added the flex option - which is probably the most common and useful one. It depends on your final goal. But all should work. In most cases, you have a grid for the rough layout and use flex for the layout within the items.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the contents of box2 into its own element you could use the 'old-fashioned' way of placement - alter the top by 25% and then adjust upwards by half that element's own height to get it positioned correctly.

```css
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper>div:not(.box2) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper>div.box2>div {
  top: 25%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">One</div>
  <div class="box2">
    <div>Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">Three</div>
  <div class="box4">Four</div>
  <div class="box5">Five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He wants the two on the same line. You got it wrong. I already solved it. Just read his comment.